# How to put a decimal when you typing in empty field angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, rxjs

I want to do some automatically input with decimal places how to achieve that?

```
<input step ="0.01" type="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

use angular **pipe** for your desire output.
example like:
{{ user.amount | number:'3.1-2'}}
where ('|') operator is pipe operator.and you can use other pipes for display to frontend.